# ios equivalent to getLastKnownLocation in Android

Tags: ios, geolocation

In android there's the method `getLastKnownLocation()`, it gets the last fetched updated location on the device.

The essential point is that this location does not even need to be fetched from your application.

I need to do the same thing in IOS, so i need the last fetched location from device, even if it wasn't from my application (because the location i need doesn't need at all to be precise)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm solving doing as follow:

I create a class GpsManager like:

```
@interface GpsManager : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocation *location;
+(GpsManager*) getShared;
@end
```

and I start it on appdelegate, this class will save the location and you can use it, it isn't util like the getLastKnownLocation() of android but hope a little.

Answer (score 0):

There's no global scope you can ask for a last known location. If YOUR app needs a location info there's no other way as YOUR app uses the CLLocationManager and its delegate methods.

Note that there's some caching involved, just check the timestamps of the CLLocation objects in – locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:

Martin